# How to set a custom class UIButton with another object of the same class?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, copy

I have a UITableView with customs cells: ParagraphTableViewCell.

```
@IBDesignable
class ParagraphTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    weak var delegate: ParagraphProtocol?

    var paragraph:Paragraph!

    @IBInspectable @IBOutlet weak var dialogueLabel: UILabel!

    @IBInspectable @IBOutlet weak var choice1Button: ChoiceButton!
    @IBInspectable @IBOutlet weak var choice2Button: ChoiceButton!
    @IBInspectable @IBOutlet weak var choice3Button: ChoiceButton!
}
```

ChoiceButton is a UIButton custom class:

```
class ChoiceButton: UIButton {

    var goToParagraphId: String!

    @IBInspectable var text: String? {
        didSet {
            self.setTitle(text, for: .normal)
            print("ChoiceButton didSet viewLabel, viewLabel = \(text!)")
        }
    }

    required init(text: String, goToParagraphId:String) {

        self.text = text
        self.goToParagraphId = goToParagraphId

        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

[image]

For my project, I created an object Paragraph which define, amongst others,  the cell content.

```
class Paragraph: NSObject {

    var id:String! 
    var dialogueLabel: UILabel!  
    var choice1Button: ChoiceButton!
    var choice2Button: ChoiceButton!
    var choice3Button: ChoiceButton!

    init(dict: NSDictionary) {

        self.dialogueLabel = UILabel()
        self.dialogueLabel.text = dict["keyLabel"]! as! String


        if dict["button1"] != nil {
            self.choice1Button=ChoiceButton(text: dict["keyLabel"]! as! String, goToParagraphId: 1)
        }

        //do the same for the other ChoiceButton

}
```

To populate my UITableView, I have a NSMutableArray of Paragraph objects.
In configureCell function, I need to set the ChoiceButton of the cell with the ChoiceButton of the Paragraph object.

```
  func configureCell(tableView: UITableView, cell: ParagraphTableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let paragraph = paragraphArray[indexPath.row] as! Paragraph
        cell.paragraph = paragraph

        //TO SET the ChoiceButton I tried :
        cell.choice1Button = paragraph.choice1Button // -> not worked

        //TO SET the ChoiceButton I tried also
        cell.choice1Button.goToParagraphId = paragraph.choice1Button.goToParagraphId
        cell.choice1Button.text = paragraph.choice1Button.text!
        // -> but the other properties of UIButton class are not set, as the state of the UIButton

        }
```

I also to try to use NSCopying in the ChoiceButton class:

```
  func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {

        let copy = ChoiceButton(text: text!, goToParagraphId: goToParagraphId)
        return copy
}
```

I don't know how to link my ChoiceButton in my cell with the ChoiceButton in the paragraph object without losing UIButton properties.

Comment: Sounds like an unusual approach... Generally, in a typical Table View format, your `Paragraph` object would contain only data - not UI objects. Is there a reason you don't want to simply design your Cell with a `UILabel` and three `ChoiceButton`s, and then assign `.text` and .`setTitle()` using the *data* in your paragraph object?

Comment: No reason, I thought it was a good idea.

Comment: OK - then I strongly suggest *not* going with that model, as you already see the first of many problems you're likely to run into.

Comment: ok thank you, i will follow your advices :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my paragraph object, with an array dictionary, inside I store the data to set my buttons:

```
class Paragraph: NSObject {

   var id:String!
   var dialogueLabel: UILabel!
   var choiceButtonArray:[Dictionary<String, String>] = []

   init(dict: NSDictionary) {

       for i in 0...2 {
            self.choiceButtonArray.insert(["text":dict[String(i)]["keyLabel"], "goToParagraphId":dict[String(i)]["nextParagraphId"], at: i)
        }
    } 
}
```

I updated my UIButton subclass, with a new func:

```
 func setInfos(text: String, goToParagraphId:String, tag:Int) {

    self.text = text
    self.goToParagraphId = goToParagraphId 
}
```

In my cell I use my array of dictionary to set the buttons' info:

```
choiceButton.setInfos(text: self.paragraph.choiceButtonArray[button]["text"]!, goToParagraphId: self.paragraph.choiceButtonArray[button]["goToParagraphId"]!)
```